# Error in link inside tooltip of newest badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, badges

Recently, I earned the Enlightened badge.

When I visit my own profile and click on the Newest  badge, I see a tooltip with the text "Awarded for: [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c/10#10)", like the image below.

[image: Profile Page]

The problem is that this is a mistake. When I click in "Learn More", I see another page with the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880306/how-to-send-a-curl-request-with-pem-certificate-via-php/33939257#33939257) that gave the badge to me. See the next image.

[image: Badge Page]

I see the same error even after hard refresh in two different browsers (firefox and chrome).

Comment: Related MetaSE? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296534/profile-page-links-to-random-answer-for-my-awarded-great-answer-badge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed. More details (and haiku) [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371004/51).